# Migrate certification with native extension

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have problem with migrate two certificate .p12, because I can't generate .air file, because I have native extension in my project and flash builder not supported to make .air file with native extension.

I tried with next command:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Flex\SDK 4.12.1 AIR 19\bin\adt.bat" -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore new.p12-migrate -storetype pkcs12 -keystore old.p12 -target native example.exe example-app.xml example.swf`

And I got message:

> Migration certificate can only be applied to desktop native installers
>   with native extension

I haven't idea how can I do that, can you please help me ?

Thanks.